# Conditions on ordinary differential equations with solutions decreasing to 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose one has the following ordinary differential equation:
$$y''(t) + a(t).y'(t) + b(t).y(t)=0$$

**Is it possible in general to impose conditions on $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ in such a way that the ODE has solutions $y(t)$ that decrease like $1/t^2$ when t tends to $\infty$ ?**

I have no huge knowledge about ODE and my question is maybe too general but even a negative answer would be interesting.